# How to get the name of item search display in url

Tags: python, django

How do i get the name of the search item display [image]in url. As shown in the image. For example i search for bag, i want the word 'bag' to be displayed in url.

```
def search_result(request):
query = request.GET.get('q', '')
if query is None:
    return redirect("shop:homepage")
else:
    item = Item.objects.all().order_by("timestamp")
    if item:
        item = item.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)  
             ).distinct()

if item.count() == 0:
    messages.error(request, "No search results found")

paginator = Paginator(item, 1)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    'search': queryset,
    'query': query,
}
return render(request, 'search_result.html', context)
```

Comment: Won't that display in the URL by default?

Comment: you make a GET form having an input with name="search", once submitted it will show in your url, in your view you can access it with request.GET.get('search')

Comment: @Arakkal When i search for men, this is what is displayed http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-result?q=men. which is correct. But when i go to next page it displayed http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-result?page=2. How do i make it display this https://127.0.0.1:8000/search?search=bag&page=2?

Comment: @alex When i search for men, this is what is displayed 127.0.0.1:8000/search-result?q=men. which is correct. But when i go to next page it displayed 127.0.0.1:8000/search-result?page=2. How do i make it display this 127.0.0.1:8000/search?search=bag&page=2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines into your view:

```
def search_result(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query is None:
        return redirect("shop:homepage")
    else:
        item = Item.objects.all().order_by("timestamp")
        if item:
            item = item.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)).distinct()

            if item.count() == 0:
                messages.error(request, "No search results found")

    paginator = Paginator(item, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        object_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        object_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        object_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    queries_without_page = request.GET.copy()
    if 'page' in queries_without_page:
        del queries_without_page['page']

    context = {
        'search': queryset,
        'object_list': object_list,
        'queries': queries_without_page
    }
    return render(request, 'search_result.html', context)
```

and here is a complete pagination for function based views:

```
{% if object_list.has_other_pages %}
    <ul>
        {% if object_list.has_previous %}
            <li>
                <a role="button" href="?{{ queries.urlencode }}&amp;page={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></span></a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled">
                <span role="button"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></span></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in object_list.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if object_list.number == i %}
                <li class="active">
                    <span role="button" class="mb-1 mt-1 mr-1 btn btn-sm btn-primary active pagination-btn">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
                </li>
            {% elif i > object_list.number|add:'-4' and i < object_list.number|add:'4' %}
                <li>
                    <a role="button" href="?{{ queries.urlencode }}&amp;page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if object_list.has_next %}
            <li>
                <a role="button" href="?{{ queries.urlencode }}&amp;page={{ object_list.next_page_number }}"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span></a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled">
                <span role="button"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. but i have just one issue here. When added your code, i searched for men it display http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-result?q=men&page=2. which is what i wanted. But how can i take off the 'q' in q=men&page=2, i just want only this men&page=2.

Comment: it doesn't work that way :) it works like a dictionary with key value

Comment: it works fine. it shows this 127.0.0.1:8000/search-result?q=men&page=2. how can i take off the q from q=men.

Comment: why do you want to get rid of q?

Comment: i think it is better that way. I use the Q lookups. Thanks